# CVXPY 1.0.24 in Python 3.+ isn't solving quad problem correctly

Tags: python-3.x, cvxpy

I am trying to maximize cx - xAx with A being positive definite, but solution is not what I it should be. Please help

I tried the problem using this data

```
A = np.array([[1595., 1098., 1133.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [1191., 1497., 1133.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [1191., 1098., 1396.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,  655.,    0.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0., 1313.,    0.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,  581.,    0.],
       [   0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,    0.,  536.]])

c = np.array([4673.36981266, 4727.12719741, 5939.49046907, 3867.69830799,
       6099.15146109, 5358.10885615, 4885.96523884])

prob = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(cp.quad_form(x,A)+c.T@x),[x>=0])

prob.solve()
```

I get DCP error with code above..

I then tried Minimize version but then get -inf as answer

```
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cp.quad_form(x,A)-c.T@x),[x>=0])

prob.solve()
```

The actual optimal solution to Max (cx - xAx) is

```
np.array([0,0,2.134,2.903,2.359,4.6266,4.508])
```

with optimal value of 42586

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to change your constraint after you changed the problem from a maximization to a minimization. For a minimization, you could try x<=0